# Compute Module Serial Interface

Tags: raspbian, serial, communication

I am attempting to use a USB to TTL cable to create a terminal interface with a Raspberry Pi compute module on a compute module development board. I followed [these](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-5-using-a-console-cable/connect-the-lead) instructions, but to no avail. The `ttyUSB0` port appears in my `/dev` folder, but when I **GNU screen** into the `ttyUSB0` port, there is no activity. After looking around, I attempted to edit the `/boot/cmdline.txt` and `/etc/inittab` files as suggested [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection), but also to no avail: Nothing changes. I have attempted to use a 2015 and a 2014 version of Raspian, but both have the same results.

Any suggestions to the next step of troubleshooting?

### EDIT:

I have found that a getty console does start on `/dev/ttyAMA0`, but once I try to connect via the TTL cable, it seems to crash as it no longer shows in `ps aux`. Thus, how can I find out what is making it crash?

Comment: Can you see the initial kernel boot log when the board is powered on?

Comment: @RonnyNilsson I managed to get it working. I followed the steps listed in the second link above and changed /boot/cmdline.txt and /etc/inittab. **I then had to set the J3 jumper so that 3.3V was selected for both VGO and VGI.** I think that was the key. The terminal took a few tries to get going.